# How to specify exact version of Office.js used?

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office-store

We're running an Outlook add-in and it looks like Microsoft have updated the version of Office.js from `16.00` to `16.01`: `outlook:{ios:"16.00",mac:"16.00",web:"16.01",win32:"16.02"}` (via https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js)

One of the changes looks to be additional verification to the abstraction of `postMessage` ensuring that the domain (including subdomain) of the child / parent are the same.

Because we host our add-in and central auth server on different subdomains and as a result, all our OAuth flows are broken in Outlook for the web.

`outlook-web-16.01.js:18 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://outlook.domain.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://auth.domain.com')`

Outlook on Desktop (both MacOS and Windows) are unaffected.

We already whitelist the domains in our manifest file:

```
<AppDomains>
  <AppDomain>https://outlook.domain.com</AppDomain>
  <AppDomain>https://outlook-staging.domain.com</AppDomain>
  <AppDomain>https://auth.domain.com</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

Is it possible to manually specify the version of Office.js that is loaded in each platform so we can upgrade at our own pace and avoid breaking changes like these?

Answer (score 1):

For this specific error, you need to add your subdomains to the appdomain/appdomains section in your manifest. See:

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/appdomains
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/appdomain

Major version changes, i.e. 16.00 -> 16.01, in general cannot be specified, and should not be rolled back to. If a host (OWA client or Outlook) is expecting a certain version (16.01) forcing it to use 16.00 would result in unexpected behavior (most likely apis just returning errors).

If you wanted to be more resilient to the changes we make to those files (i.e. changes we make to 16.01) you could pull the files off appsforoffice and selfhost them. But this is not supported/recommended. This means that any bug fixes or improvements we made to those files would be missed.

Comment: We do specify those domains in the manifest file and have since before we went through the validation process.

We looked into self hosting, but because of the way Office.JS uses separate JS files for separate platforms this seems problematic.

Comment: It's also important to note that this specific error has only been occurring over the past day or two which is why I attribute it to a version change.

Comment: Given that desktop versions appear unaffected, how do we file this as a bug in expected behaviour and seek a timely fix?

Comment: I *think* this might be a different issue than the appdomains piece on the manifest. Are you getting this error when using the dialog API?  If so, in which Operating systems and browsers?

Comment: Yes, we're using the dialog API. It's currently happening on MacOS on Safari and Chrome. Haven't verified on Windows environments yet but can test shortly.

Comment: Works on Windows 10 with Edge, still failing on MacOS Safari / Chrome

Comment: I still have this issue in MacOS Chrome. Was there a fix?

Comment: Hi Jim, no there has not been a fix. To help us reproduce, could you give us the error message you get with MacOS Chrome and checked that your AppDomains list is correct? Did this issue surface for you recently, and what API are you using to hit the error? What build of OWA are you using?