# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://outlook.office.com') does not match

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an add-in for Outlook. I am using the [Dialog API](http://ttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins).

I get an error when using my adding in Outlook for the Web:

> Failed to execute `postMessage` on `DOMWindow`: The target origin provided (`https://outlook.office.com`) does not match the recipient window's origin (`https://myIp:port`)

It appears when I call `Office.context.ui.messageParent`.

Anyone faced the same problem and know the fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify exact version of Office.js used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092744/how-to-specify-exact-version-of-office-js-used)

Comment: It's is appearing even before I call 'Office.context.ui.messageParent'. As soon as dialog opens, the below error comes:
Failed to execute postMessage on DOMWindow: The target origin provided (https://outlook.office.com) does not match the recipient window's origin (https://myIp:port)

Comment: @MarcLaFleur can you please help? Has it been fixed in owa which is version 16.01 currently

Comment: Does calling Office.context.ui.messageParent actually work and you're only seeing that error in the console?

Comment: Just to be clear, based on what we know, the error "Failed to execute postMessage on DOMWindow …" is superficial and can be ignored, it does not impact the functionality of Office.context.ui.messageParent.